# grails 2: reload of controller, break points, and shutdown

Tags: grails-2.0, grails-controller

I experience some strange problems with a brand new grails 2 installation and project.

my setup:

- windows 7
- grails 2.1.1
- intellij

problems:

1. when storing an entity i set a flash.message="foo"+x. grails caches this code (not value). when i change it to "bar"+x then grails does not pick up the change. i have to stop, grails clean, and start again. takes forever.
2. in my grails controller i query a web service. when the web service is offline then i get a FileNotFoundException. so i wrap the code in a try-catch. now i still get that FileNotFoundException, and the browser output with the error 500 even shows my code snipped with the try-catch.
3. stopping grails does not stop the java process. i have to kill it using the task manager. this happens for both ways of starting: ctrl-alt-g run-app and then stopping with the skull icon, and run in debug mode and then stopping with the red button.
4. break points don't work. no matter where i set a break point in my controller, it never stops there.

Any idea what could be wrong?

I expected grails v2 to be less painful than v1, but so far it's really giving me a hard time.

Comment: about the controller reloading: i seem to be affected by this bug: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8573#comment-72570